# how to decide between simple past and past perfect?

Tags: grammar, perfect-aspect

The question is to find error if there is one.

The current economic scenario (a)/ could possibly undo (b)/ the growth that followed (c)/ the economic liberalization of 1991. (d)/ No error (e)

I am confused between **the growth that followed** and the **growth that had followed**.

what should be used here? please explain.

Comment: The sentence talks about 'the current scenario' and a situation in the past. It _doesn't_ talk about a past incident and something that had already happened before that. Does that help?

Comment: @KateBunting according to j.c. nesfiled English grammar
present perfect is used whenever we wish to say that some action had been completed before another was commenced. the current growth started long ago, so we can use past perfect?

Comment: I think you mean the _past_ perfect? The action has to have been completed before another _past_ action. The growth didn't come before a past incident, did it?

Comment: @KateBunting the book says the action must be commenced in the past, but it does not say anything about the completion of the action. The current growth might be started a long time ago and it still continues.

Comment: The past perfect is *the past of the past*. This expression isn't the past of anything else that's past. In fact, it's the *future* of a past event.

Comment: You quoted the book as saying _some action **had been completed** before another was commenced_. The point is that the 'other' action has to be in the past too. Suppose your sentence read: _[An incident in 2000] undid the growth that **had followed** the economic liberalisation of 1991_.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you are right, your explanation seems valid to me. Thanks